# Use of correct Issue Types in Jira

Tags: jira

I have started new project and I want to document it in Jira and wanted that each step has been logged in Jira so that in future it will be help full for me , therefore small task like
1.Create Git-hub project with the new project name
2.Create a VS solution and push it to git
3.Create a Jenkins job and configure the VM

issue like these comes under which tags in JIRA?? These are obviously not a bug or improvement ?

Answer (score 0):

Jira provides lots of issue types for you to use. But I still don't know what's your purpose to use Jira, just log these steps? If yes, why choose Jira, it's not a suitable one.
Jira has the general issue type like Epic, Story, Task, Sub-task and so on. Each issue has its workflow, like todo, in progress, done, etc. This can be used to manage the project.